# Validating ISO-8061 dates with the Decoder approach

Tags: typescript, fp-ts

For simple use, the Decoder approach has been working well using `io-ts`:

```
import { isRight } from 'fp-ts/Either';
import * as D from 'io-ts/Decoder';

const thing = D.struct({
  id: D.number,
  createdAt: D.string,
});

export const isValidThing = (candidate: unknown): boolean =>
  isRight(thing.decode(candidate));
```

However, now I'd like to actually validate dates more thoroughly. I half-way expected to be able to do something like this:

```
import { DateFromISOString } from 'io-ts-types/lib/DateFromISOString';

const thing = D.struct({
  id: D.number,
  createdAt: DateFromISOString
});
```

but of course, it's not that easy:

```
ERROR: src/middleware/validators/event.ts:7:3 - error TS2322: Type 'DateFromISOStringC' is not assignable to type 'Decoder<unknown, Date>'.
  The types returned by 'decode(...)' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'Validation<Date>' is not assignable to type 'Either<DecodeError, Date>'.
      Type 'Left<Errors>' is not assignable to type 'Either<DecodeError, Date>'.
        Type 'Left<Errors>' is not assignable to type 'Left<DecodeError>'.
          Type 'Errors' is not assignable to type 'DecodeError'.
            Type 'ValidationError[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Concat<DecodeError<string>>': _tag, left, right

    createdAt: DateFromISOString
```

Clearly, I've misunderstood. Is there a simple path to date validation using decoders and `struct`?

Edit: it's worth noting that this does work with the older, non-experimental method:

```
import * as t from 'io-ts';
import { DateFromISOString } from 'io-ts-types';

const thing = t.type({
  id: t.number,
  createdAt: DateFromISOString
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be [ISO-8601](https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html) dates? 

[ISO-8061](https://www.iso.org/standard/75609.html) is for Alpine ski-bindings ⛷️

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer this one for the record, and if anyone has a better way (perhaps using `.asDecoder()`, which I have been unable to get quite right) then I'll happily accept that one instead.

Defining a new `Decoder` seems to do roughly what I was hoping for:

```
const ISODateTime: D.Decoder<unknown, Date> = pipe(
  D.string,
  D.parse((s) => {
    const d = new Date(s);
    return isNaN(d.getTime())
      ? D.failure(s, 'not a valid date format')
      : D.success(d);
  })
);

const thing = D.struct({
  id: D.number,
  createdAt: ISODateTime
});

assert(
  isRight(
    thing.decode({
      id: 1,
      createdAt: '2021-06-26T01:39:06.693Z'
    })
  )
); // true
assert(
  isRight(
    thing.decode({
      id: 1,
      createdAt: 'x1'
    })
  )
); // false
```

though of course it doesn't definitively prove that the incoming string is in ISO-8061 format, since `Date.parse` is quite permissive.

Comment: One improvement to your solution is to combine existing Decoders like `D.string` to build up your date decoder rather than re-implementing the string decoding logic yourself. This can be done with `pipe(D.string, D.parse(str => ...))`. See here for an example - https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts/blob/master/Decoder.md#the-parse-combinator

Comment: I knew there must be a way to do that! I'll edit, ty.

Comment: Although, how would one provide the specific error message? I'm assuming `withMessage` could be leveraged somehow...

Comment: You can pass the decoder name to `D.failure` and it will come up in the error that io-ts produces (e.g. `ISODateTime` in your case). Formatting errors from `.decode()` to a specific format is a rather tricky endeavour unfortunately. You can use `D.draw` which is built-in error reporter to get a nicely formatted string: https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts/blob/master/Decoder.md#built-in-error-reporter

Comment: Yes, I've played with `draw` a bit... but I think at some point I'm going to need to investigate writing a custom reporter that generates an array with one error per element.